# Get MySQL result-set size from query

Tags: php, mysql, caching

Is it possible to get the size of the result-set when doing a query?

I need to set a proper MySQL `cache_limit` (MB) and therefore I am trying out some queries, but I need to know the sizes of the result-sets to fine-tune my cache configurations.

What exactly does `query_cache_limit` do when measuring the size of a query (or result)...

Comment: So you want to size in bytes of a mysql query result? And what mysql_fetch function are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rouph estimate you coud try

```
<?php
// This is only an example, the numbers below will
// differ depending on your system

echo memory_get_usage() . "\n"; // 36640

$a = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo memory_get_usage() . "\n"; // 57960

unset($a);

echo memory_get_usage() . "\n"; // 36744

?>
```

or

`echo strlen(serialize(mysql_fetch_assoc($result)));`

Comment: strlen won't always be indicative of the byte length, as there may be things like multibyte strings in the response (which take up one character but several bytes)

Comment: Very true, like I said this would only be an estimate.
Considering the problem it is likly Camran would know if there would be an issue with multibyte strings. 
Also consider that serialized string might not represent an accurate size compared to a array

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to measure the size of data sent from your mysql server to your php process:

## Pure SQL

Do your query and execute `SHOW SESSION STATUS` directly after it. You will get several statistics, including the sent and received bytes:

```
Bytes_received  191
Bytes_sent      120
```

Subtract the bytes from a `SHOW SESSION STATUS` query alone, and you have the exact values.

## mysqlnd

PHP 5.3 offers the "MySQL Native Driver", which gives you some nice options to debug your connection.

Do your query and then call `mysqli_get_connection_stats`. It returns the network statistics, too:

```
Array
(
    [bytes_sent] => 43
    [bytes_received] => 80
    ...
```

You need to use mysqli and mysqlnd here, but you get more accurate numbers as with the pure SQL solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Petah's method of using memory_get_usage before and after is probably the easiest way. To get a more accurate result, you could use `mb_strlen` but you'd need to loop through each row in the result and each field of each row, summing up the total as you go. You'd also need to use the correct encoding.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php